# PHP VK API как правильно выходить из цикла и продолжать его

Tags: php, api, вконтакте, циклы

Как сделать правильнее или проще, если сработало условие ошибки 14, останавливать цикл и после того как капча отправилась продолжать цикл с того же места.

https://pastebin.com/vpeyeZni

Answer (score 0):

Вы передаёте id's пользователей:

```
$userid = array("484674859","6468653", "140893756");
```

Так запоминайте пользователя или ключ массива на котором вышла каптча. Потом обрезайте массив до значения и запускайте цикл с новым массивом.

Обрезать можно так (пример с ключом):

```
$newuserid = array_slice($userid, 2); // где 2 - до какого ключа обрезать массив
```